# How to ensure gradle executes main class only after building app to 100%?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, build, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a kotlin application that acts as a kind of repl,  with input blocking. When I do `./gradlew run` , it run the application but only after partially building the app. As such, it distorts the console with the build logs.

```
> Task :run 
MY_CONSOLE:
<==========---> 83% EXECUTING [15s]
> :run
```

I want it to run the main class after having fully built it to 100%, so that there's no distortion.  How do I accomplish this?

My gradle build file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.11'
}

group 'com.me.shiny-interpreter'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
mainClassName = "interpreter.Repl"



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/hotkeytlt/maven") }

}
configurations {
    ktlint
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    compile 'com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-jvm:0.4.0-alpha-3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.4'
    ktlint "com.github.shyiko:ktlint:0.31.0"


}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The progress that Gradle shows you is the estimated progress of the whole build process which consists of multiple steps, including the `run` task. That being said, your application is actually fully built and the last missing 17% are  from the application run itself. In any case, rest assured your app is assembled correctly.